# Recharts set Y-axis value base of number displayed

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Hi I'm trying to use Recharts to display some data but I have ran into a problem. The numbers I'm tying to display are too big and my Y-axis gets cut off by the webpage. Is their a way to set or customize the Y-axis values to display 10K, 10M and etc instead of 10,000 and 10,000,000 depending on the data?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There isn't a way to have the Y-axis to do it automatically, but if your data is being input into the recharts as ints you can add `tickFormatter` to the Y-axis tab. You can have `tickFormatter` to equal a function that takes in 1 variable which will be the Y-axis tick value (as an int) and return the number in the format you want it.

this function takes in the Y-axis as a int and returns it as a string

```
const DataFormater = (number) => {
  if(number > 1000000000){
    return (number/1000000000).toString() + 'B';
  }else if(number > 1000000){
    return (number/1000000).toString() + 'M';
  }else if(number > 1000){
    return (number/1000).toString() + 'K';
  }else{
    return number.toString();
  }
}
```

in area chart `<YAxis tickFormatter={DataFormater}/>`

Comment: it works fine, just minor improvement for all return, ---> return parseInt(number / ......)

Comment: Can we use html tags inside DataFormater function like

const DataFormater = (number) => {
  if(number > 1000000000){
    return <span>Number is{(number/1000000000).toString()}</span>
  }else if(number > 1000000){
    return (number/1000000).toString() + 'M';
  }else if(number > 1000){
    return (number/1000).toString() + 'K';
  }else{
    return number.toString();
  }
}

Answer (score 16):

You can also use [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) which is a standard JS library. It will format large numbers as requested.

##### Recharts Y Axis

```
<YAxis
  tickFormatter={(value) =>
    new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      notation: "compact",
      compactDisplay: "short",
    }).format(value)
  }
>
```

##### Sample Console Output of `Intl.NumberFormat`

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  notation: "compact",
  compactDisplay: "short"
}).format(987654321);
// → 988M
```

Answer (score 1):

[@CSstudent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52321334/9430588) is 100% correct but you don't really have to calculate those abbreviations manually. You could use [`js-number-abbreviate` library](https://github.com/domharrington/js-number-abbreviate).

This way, you could do this:

```js
import abbreviate from "number-abbreviate";

...

<YAxis tickFormatter={abbreviate} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let kFormatter = (num) => {
        return Math.abs(num) > 999
         ? Math.sign(num) * (Math.abs(num) / 1000).toFixed(1) + "k"
         : Math.sign(num) * Math.abs(num);
    };
    <YAxis  dataKey="Y1" label={{ value: 'Y1'}} tickFormatter={kFormatter} />
```